# Different results from different order of list creation

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have these two versions to the same question: "Make a new list that has all the elements less than 5 from this list in it and print out this new list." They are the same but only different in the order of the line *"new_a = [ ]"*, which delivers different results. How come? Thanks in advance!

```
#Ver1
a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
new_a = []
for element in a: 
    if element < 5:
       new_a.append(element)
       print(new_a)

#Ver2
a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
for element in a: 
    if element < 5:
       new_a = []
       new_a.append(element)
       print(new_a)
```

Comment: in Ver2, new_a is blanked out every time element <5 is true

Comment: Traverse through your code manually. You'll find where the difference is.

Comment: This is a perfectly fine question, I wonder where the down votes are coming from.

Answer (score 3):

Your second version creates a new empty `new_a` list every time it encounters an element less than `5`, thereby effectively deleting all the previous entries. A more efficient way to do this would be using a list comprehension

```
>>> [i for i in a if i < 5]
[1, 1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 2):

In #1, you are defining a single results list and then appending to it sequentially.

In #2, you are defining a new empty list for each loop.

The effect of this is that the second solution does not store results from previous iterations of the `for` loop.

---

There are a couple of ways you can make your code more readable:

**Generator function**

Define a generator function and remove boilerplate list creation code.

```
def custom_filter(lst, i):
    for element in lst: 
        if element < i:
            yield element

res = list(custom_filter(a, 5))
```

**Comprehensions**

You can make this lazy and iterate a generator comprehension:

```
res = (i for i in a if i < 5)
```

Or you can use a list comprehension:

```
res = [i for i in a if i < 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

In the second version, as you defined `new_a = []` inside the loop it creates new empty list in every iteration. And the value is getting updated to new list like below:

```
[1]
[1]
[2]
[3]
```

In your first version also if you want output `[1, 1, 2, 3]` you need to remove indent before `print(new_a)` like below:

```
a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
new_a = []
for element in a: 
    if element < 5:
       new_a.append(element)

print(new_a)
```

Comment: So with 1st version, how can I remove indent if you insist on using the same code? (sorry to bother you, I just started self-teaching with Python a few days ago) Thanks in advance

Comment: @Hạ Vy Võ: Updated. Do you need any further clarification ?

Comment: @HạVyVõ: Please confirm the answer so that it will help others

Answer (score 0):

In the second version you set list `new_a = []` in every iteration. You set it to `[]` and then `append` the element.

In the first version you keep appending to the previous iteration.